# Installing Oracle XE on Mac Leopard (issue with a segmentation fault)

Tags: macos, oracle10g, osx-leopard, oracle-xe, failed-installation

I am trying to install Oracle XE 10.2 on my Mac Leopard. However, it doesn't go without a lot of fuzz. Thankfully I have this tutorial at my disposal: http://bit.ly/a4rc4O

The only pain I am left with is the following command that fails (from the cfgtoollogs/configToolAllCommands).

```
/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/netca /orahome /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 /orahnam OraDb10g_home1 /instype custom /inscomp client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano /insprtcl tcp /cfg local /authadp NO_VALUE /nodeinfo NO_VALUE /responseFile /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
```

Which generates the following output:

```
#
# The exception above was detected in native code outside the VM
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.4.2-92 mixed mode)
#
/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/jre/bin/java: line 2: 27805 Segmentation fault      /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Home/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/jre/lib/ext:/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/lib/ext $*
```

I want to run Oracle on my Mac, as software I need relies on Oracle database. I fetched the binary from the Oracle website, and is supposed to work.

This box runs on Intel Core 2 Duo, running Leopard 10.5.8 and has Java 1.5.0 available. I more information is needed to analyze this, please comment and I will edit. Also some pointers where to look for would be nice. Thanks a bunch for help or trying to :)

Here is the full output from the log:

```
Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraDb10g_home1
    Parameter "instype" = custom
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "nodeinfo" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:

# This JavaNativeCrash log describes the Java state at a Native Crash in a Java application.
# The corresponding native state can be found in the crash log generated by CrashReporter.

# If this error is reproducible, please report it with the following information: 
#   1. Provide the steps to reproduce, a test case, and any relevant information
#   2. This JavaNativeCrash_pid<num>.crash.log (Java state)
#   3. The corresponding <name>.crash.log (native state; generated by CrashReporter)
# File report at: http://bugreport.apple.com/

An unexpected exception has been detected in native code outside the VM.
Unexpected Signal : Bus Error occurred at PC=0x9714E22B
Function=[Unknown.]
Library=/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

NOTE: We are unable to locate the function name symbol for the error
      just occurred. Please refer to release documentation for possible
      reason and solutions.


Current Java thread:
 at oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.getDNSDomain(Native Method)
 at oracle.net.ca.ConfigureProfile.setDefaultProfileParams(Unknown Source)
 at oracle.net.ca.InitialSetup.setupConfigObjects(Unknown Source)
 at oracle.net.ca.InitialSetup.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(Unknown Source)

Dynamic libraries and executable:
[0x00002458-0x0000881e] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Home/bin/java
[0x0001071c-0x000157b0] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/JavaVM
[0x91bf2730-0x91cefb56] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
[0x91ab9780-0x91ac071e] /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
[0x971250a0-0x972596d0] /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
[0x957cca60-0x959ae953] /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
[0x91ac27c0-0x91ad7335] /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
[0x911931f0-0x91286765] /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
[0x900f2a74-0x901ba452] /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
[0x93ccb8cc-0x93cd602c] /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
[0x909c5ea8-0x90a525dd] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
[0x9552fe4c-0x95562417] /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
[0x943e9e70-0x943e9e92] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
[0x95da32c0-0x95f08aee] /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
[0x97b7d000-0x97ba66b3] /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
[0x94619fb4-0x94661005] /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
[0x93bca2b0-0x93bcb1e7] /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
[0x957442b0-0x957c50d2] /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
[0x951e45f8-0x952010c7] /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
[0x90ea0b58-0x90f8cd72] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
[0x97e26f7c-0x97e64a33] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
[0x950e0880-0x95187582] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
[0x946cb370-0x94730dd0] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
[0x91a8a200-0x91ab70f1] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
[0x931be318-0x93239030] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
[0x9117c30c-0x9118ce6c] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
[0x92d095f0-0x92d83fd1] /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
[0x936cd100-0x936d4899] /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
[0x91a6a00c-0x91a70bdb] /usr/lib/libbsm.dylib
[0x93198cdc-0x931b7ab1] /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
[0x961537b0-0x963a0876] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Libraries/libhotspot.dylib
[0x00035268-0x0003e8fd] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Libraries/libverify.dylib
[0x00046760-0x0005bcc5] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Libraries/libjava.jnilib
[0x0006bea8-0x00075723] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Libraries/libzip.jnilib
[0x05d65780-0x05e54029] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
[0x95f7ce60-0x95f7ce82] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
[0x96464f7c-0x96464f9e] /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
[0x93bc8fdc-0x93bc8ffe] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
[0x0558ffb4-0x055922ac] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Libraries/libfontmanager.jnilib
[0x948e1944-0x94ff3252] /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
[0x95ccb4e0-0x95d5359a] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
[0x97bd9544-0x97c647cf] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
[0x93d48ef0-0x943872d0] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
[0x9036744c-0x903bdae7] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
[0x933d95a4-0x934259b1] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
[0x9600ae08-0x96108ffa] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
[0x936bc704-0x936cb9fd] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
[0x90473228-0x904d3a2a] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
[0x963bd8dc-0x96456050] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
[0x93d37ae8-0x93d44feb] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
[0x91396600-0x91430c92] /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
[0x97ab4720-0x97b76938] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
[0x90a6dfdc-0x90a6dffe] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
[0x919eabf0-0x91a55e9a] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
[0x95a4b540-0x95a7780d] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
[0x937b7660-0x93bc3bdd] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
[0x915a8090-0x91960be7] /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
[0x9369c3dc-0x936b7f7f] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
[0x9736a254-0x9738b7ee] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
[0x937091ac-0x9370cd15] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
[0x978e4374-0x978fd35f] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
[0x95b81d30-0x95b83dce] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
[0x95bd424c-0x95bf8a30] /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
[0x903c1724-0x9046023d] /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
[0x973aa6c0-0x97475b8c] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
[0x9144a760-0x9156ef60] /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
[0x957426c0-0x95742fe9] /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
[0x95c40720-0x95cc109a] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
[0x975680a0-0x97848f82] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
[0x90a8018c-0x90ce4bbd] /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
[0x9728ce58-0x9729411f] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
[0x90e66844-0x90e97182] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
[0x974e8cac-0x97545e4e] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
[0x978e2fdc-0x978e2ffe] /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
[0x97353fa4-0x97353fbd] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/InstallServer.framework/Versions/A/InstallServer
[0x9159d3d0-0x915a6b37] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
[0x91a7bfa0-0x91a88719] /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
[0x9324c3c0-0x93287d8f] /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
[0x97ab3190-0x97ab3ffd] /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
[0x95fbaefc-0x95fd1b76] /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
[0x932be1e0-0x93311b3b] /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
[0x97ca4ec0-0x97cb0fff] /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
[0x904f4500-0x9098927d] /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
[0x16d30c30-0x16f115d4] /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
[0x90a738f8-0x90a7e334] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
[0x95bfdb54-0x95c39c35] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
[0x1608ffd0-0x16093e42] /Library/InputManagers/Edit in ODBEditor/Edit in ODBEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Edit in ODBEditor
[0x90e46fac-0x90e46fce] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
[0x95febe38-0x95ff03e7] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
[0x945a8704-0x945aa8f6] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
[0x93cdab38-0x93d28a0b] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HTMLRendering.framework/Versions/A/HTMLRendering
[0x9331f604-0x9332d49d] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
[0x93335230-0x933b7897] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
[0x9346017c-0x934a07ad] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/NavigationServices.framework/Versions/A/NavigationServices
[0x95ff2048-0x960049e9] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
[0x933181f0-0x9331c6ac] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
[0x95da02bc-0x95da1a65] /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
[0x161c9630-0x161ca795] /Library/InputManagers/SIMBL/SIMBL.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SIMBL
[0x973625b4-0x97368633] /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGATS.A.dylib
[0x90e1dea8-0x90e3fb2b] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Shortcut.framework/Versions/A/Shortcut
[0x901d598c-0x901de6a2] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HelpData.framework/Versions/A/HelpData
[0x160b8014-0x160c3eb6] /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib32/libnjni10.jnilib
[0x19c5b100-0x1ae42450] /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib32/libclntsh.dylib.10.1
[0x1b0f0524-0x1b21ee9e] /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib32/libnnz10.dylib
[0x176ff3d4-0x1770589e] /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib32/libldapjclnt10.jnilib

Local Time = Fri Aug 27 17:31:52 2010
Elapsed Time = 794
#
# The exception above was detected in native code outside the VM
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.4.2-92 mixed mode)
#
/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/jre/bin/java: line 2: 27805 Segmentation fault      /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Home/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/jre/lib/ext:/Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/lib/ext $*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty lame: changing the environment variable ORACLE_SID to lowercase, fixed the netca command. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing oracle on VM. for more instructions, visit https://tech.lds.org/wiki/Oracle_VM

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is Oracle XE?  I can't find a download for that on Oracle's web site.  Did you extract the RPM contents of the Linux RPM in order to do the install?  I would love to get XE working, but I can only find instructions for Oracle 10g.